# Selected list element does not stay selected (after updated via ajax request)

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I want to create a select-able list where each of the list elements comes from an ajax request.
This works fine. But the issue which I am unable to solve is, that the selected list element does not stay selected after the update(new Ajax Request). Everything else works as expected.
Thanks for your help.

Here is the code of my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script src='/sm/scripts/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='/sm/scripts/knockout.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='/sm/scripts/knockout.mapping.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <select data-bind="options:SiteData , selectedOptions:selectedSiteData , optionsText: 'SiteName'" size="5" multiple="true"></select>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedSiteData, null, 2)"></pre>
    <script src='/sm/viewModel.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of my viewmodel.js:

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.SiteData = ko.mapping.fromJSON([{}]);
    self.selectedSiteData = ko.observableArray();
    this.refresh = function() {
      $.getJSON("/sm/allsites", function(data) {
          ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.SiteData);
      });
    };
    self.refresh();
    setInterval(self.refresh, 3000);
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `selectedSiteData` consists of references to objects in `SiteData`, with highlighting being determined by object-identity comparisons. Once you refresh `SiteData`, all the objects are completely new in identity, even if some of them contain the same data as the previous ones, so none of the references in `selectedSiteData` compare equal to them.

I think you're pretty much going to have to loop through `selectedSiteData` and compare each member's data (maybe an `id` field) with the data in each member of `SiteData`, replacing the former with the latter if it matches.